# Why StreamEx force me to add "? extends" to variable type when collecting to list?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, streamex

I noticed that in the case below standard Java stream better "calculate" variable type than StreamEx.
This is odd, because people love StreamEx and use it everywhere, but then code become polluted with "?".
I want to use `List<Class<?>` but StreamEx force me to use `List<? extends Class<?>>`. Could someone explain why StreamEx works this way? Can I somehow use the desired variable type with StreamEx ?

```java
private static List<? extends Class<?>> 
fooList_StreamEx_Compiles(List<Integer> input) {
    return StreamEx.of(input)
            .map(x -> foo())
            .toList();
}

private static List<Class<?>> 
fooList_StreamEx_Error(List<Integer> input) {
    return StreamEx.of(input)
            .map(x -> foo())
// Error: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ?>> 
// cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Class<?>>
            .toList();
}

private static List<Class<?>> fooList(List<Integer> input) {
    return input
            .stream()
            .map(x -> foo())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Class<?> foo() {
    return String.class;
}
```

I'm using StreamEx 0.7.0 and Java 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a `StreamEx` issue. When you use `collect(Collectors.toList())` on the `StreamEx`, it works equally well. The problem is connected with the `toList()` convenience method, which the standard `Stream` doesn’t even offer. It’s a general problem that `StreamEx` is not to blame for.

The `toList` method on `StreamEx` has the following signature:

```java
public List<T> toList()
```

In a perfect world, it would be legal to create a list parameterized with a super-type, i.e.

```java
public <R super T> List<R> toList()
```

but this syntax had been omitted when Java’s generics were created. The `toArray` methods of both, `Collection` and `Stream` suffer from a similar limitation; they can not declare the resulting array’s element type to be a super type of the collection’s element type. But since an actual array’s store operation is checked, those methods simply allow any element type. For a `List` result, subject to type erasure, this is not possible.

When using `collect(Collectors.toList())` on the other hand, it’s possible to create a list with a super type due to `collect`’s signature:

```java
<R,​A> R collect​(Collector<? super T,​A,​R> collector)
```

which allows to pass in a `Collector` parameterized with a super type (`? super T`) that in most scenarios will be inferred from the target type.

---

This limitation of the `toList` declaration interacts with another limitation, the unreasonable handling of wildcard types. I’m not sure whether the cause of this problem lies in the compiler or specification, but at the `map(x -> foo())` step, the wildcard type got captured and such a captured type will be considered different to any other captured wildcard type, even when it stems from the same source.

When I compile your code with `javac`, it says:

```
error: incompatible types: List<Class<CAP#1>> cannot be converted to List<Class<?>>
                    .toList();
                           ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
```

The `CAP#1` is a captured type. All captured types get numbered, to distinguish them. As said, each of them is considered a distinct type, different from every other.

`Class<?>` is a supertype of `Class<CAP#1>`, so it works with `collect` which allows to collect to a list parameterized with that supertype, as said above, but not with `toList`.

You can fix this by using the return type `List<? extends Class<?>>`, to denote that the list’s actual element type is a subtype of `Class<?>`, but the better option is to force the compiler not to use a captured type:

```java
private static List<Class<?>> fooList_StreamEx_Solved(List<Integer> input) {
    return StreamEx.of(input)
            .<Class<?>>map(x -> foo())
            .toList();
}
```

Don’t worry if you didn’t fully understand the necessity to insert the explicit type here, I’m not claiming that the behavior of Java compilers was comprehensible at all when wildcard types are involved…

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Often people use StreamEx even in simple cases just because `toList()` is much simpler both for reading and writing. But with all these limitations I would say that we should never use `toList` shortcut. Cause variable type is much more important than beautiful code in the stream. A single stream may produce variable that used everywhere in the project.

Comment: @OlegVazhnev there is no danger in using `toList()` when it fits. You can still use the alternative when it doesn’t. Letting the wildcard issue aside, it’s not different to, e.g. `List<Object> result = streamEx.map(x -> "").toList();` that doesn’t work and needs help like `List<Object> result = streamEx.<Object>map(x -> "").toList();` which still is slightly simpler than resorting to `collect(Collectors.toList())`.